# My variable does not change its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, touch-event

I succeeded to design a drag-drop with mousedown and mousemove. Here is the code:

```
$('.item').live( {
    mousedown : function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        if (self.selectedItem != null) {
            self.selectedItem.removeClass('selected');
            self.selectedItem = null;
            firstSelectedItem = null;
            switchingItem = false;
        } else {
            self.selectedItem = $elem.addClass('selected');
            firstSelectedItem = $elem;
            switchingItem = true;
        }
    },
    mousemove : function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        if (switchingItem === true && $elem.attr('id') != firstSelectedItem.attr('id')) {
            self._swap(firstSelectedItem, $elem);
            self.selectedItem.removeClass('selected');
            self.selectedItem = null;
            firstSelectedItem = null;
            switchingItem = false;
        }
    },
});
```

I try in vain to do it again with the touchevents. Except that $this value is the same to touchstart and touchmove, so the swapping does not work:

```
$('.item').live( {
    touchstart : function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var $elem = $(this);
        if (self.selectedItem != null) {
            self.selectedItem.removeClass('selected');
            self.selectedItem = null;
            firstSelectedItem = null;
            switchingItem = false;
        } else {
            self.selectedItem = $elem.addClass('selected');
            firstSelectedItem = $elem;
            switchingItem = true;
            console.log (firstSelectedItem.attr('id'));
        }
    },
    touchmove : function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this);
        if (switchingItem === true && $elem.attr('id') != firstSelectedItem.attr('id')) {
            self._swap(firstSelectedItem, $elem);
            self.selectedItem.removeClass('selected');
            self.selectedItem = null;
            firstSelectedItem = null;
            switchingItem = false;
        }
    },
});
```

What to do?

Thank you so much

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I don't  know. Can I give you the rest of script file to try?